# Why is the $\theta$ term of QCD violating charge and parity (CP) symmetries?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, tensor-calculus

From the non-trivial nature of the QCD vacuum, the Lagrangian is augmented with a term like

\begin{equation}
 \theta \frac{g^2}{32 \pi^2} G_{\mu \nu}^a \tilde{G}^{a, \mu \nu}
\end{equation}

where $ \tilde{G}^{a,\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} G^a_{ \rho \sigma} $ is the dual field strength tensor. This term is said to violate CP, giving rise to the strong CP problem.

I understand the CP violation comes from the [epsilon tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) in the dual field strength but I am looking for a simple straightforward demonstration of the CP violating nature of a term like $G \tilde{G}$.

Comment: I have answered this question here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111178/6178

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yang-Mills CP violation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111167/yang-mills-cp-violation)

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there another way to answer without using electric and magnetic fields, nor differential forms ?

Comment: Well the simplest answer then is what you wrote, namely that it's because the Levi-Civita is a pseudo-tensor, so this term changes sign under parity.